# Python: split a text file into multiple working sessions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, loops

How can I define my worker to do stuff for the first 4 first lines from the `test.txt` file and then go into the next worker and continue with the next 4 items in list (so 5-8) and so on. (3rd worker 9-12).

**Code:**

```
import time

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    Mylist = f.readlines()

N = 4
def worker():
    for Item in Mylist:
        #Do Stuff
        print(Item)
    print("Done Session")    
    time.sleep(2)


def main():
    worker()
    worker()
    worker()
    return main()

main()
```

**`test.txt`** contains the numbers from 1 to 12:

```
1
2
3
...
12
```

output should look like:

```
1
2
3
4
Done Session
5
6
7
8
Done Session
9
10
11
12
Done Session
```

Also `main()` should stop returning after there are no more items in list, so in this example it would stop the loop after the 12 item from list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need this worker() function, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/522578/11607969) to iterate a list of items with index:

```py
def worker():
    for idx, Item in enumerate(Mylist):
        if idx % N == 0:
            print("Done Session")
            time.sleep(2)
        print(Item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use range and read specific indexes of List

```
import time

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    Mylist = f.readlines()

N = 4
def worker(index_of_worker):
    for x in range(index_of_worker*4, index_of_worker*4+N):
        print(Mylist[x])
    print("Done Session")    
    time.sleep(2)


def main():
    worker(0)
    worker(1)
    worker(2)
    return main()
    

main()
```